# How to pass different parameters to the same form function based on different urls

Tags: 7, forms

I have a custom model containing two paths. Each path goes to the same function. I wanna to send to each page arguments specific parameter and reception on the function then pass the hidden value to submit function.

```
  $items['parkingcalculator_normal'] = array(
    'title' => t('Parking calculator'),
    'description' => 'Parking Calculator Page',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('parkingcalulator_form',0),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  $items['parkingcalculator_valet'] = array(
    'title' => t('Parking calculator'),
    'description' => 'Parking Calculator Page',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('parkingcalulator_form',0 ),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
function parkingcalulator_form($form, &$form_state , $type){...}
```

but the function does not take the parameter and does not pass the value in the hidden form type to

```
function parkingcalulator_form_submit($form, &$form_state ,$type)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove $form from the submit function and just keep the $form_state.

The function would look like

```
function parkingcalulator_form_submit(&$form_state ,$type)
```

Comment: The Drupal Form API defines the signature for a submit function - you can't just change it at will. This will not work.

Answer (score 0):

In `parkingcalulator_form($form, &$form_state, $type)`, create a hidden form element to store the data you need for your submit function:

```
$form['type'] = array('#type' => 'hidden', '#value' => $type);
```

Then in your submit function `parkingcalulator_form_submit($form, &$form_state)` you can access that value:

```
$type = $form_state['values']['type'];
```